# Does the drive where python.exe is stored matter?

Tags: python, system

I'm opening D:\Project... and trying to run commands such as pip install, but I get the error that pip is not recognized. Pip is definitely included in my paths as C:\python...

I wonder if there is some kind of cross drive issue as I migrated my projects from my C: to D: drive recently.

I need to submit an IT ticket to reinstall python, so I hope it won't come to that.

Comment: Try entering the whole path to pip in the command, as mentioned in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53103892/6590393, and see if it works. There is also a suggestion of creating a virtual environment in your external drive.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use virtual environments. Otherwise your main environment will become a mess. Here's a [guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).